# issue saving summernote in DB

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, summernote

I have an issue saving summernote value in DB using ajax but when i dont use ajax everything is working.

to make it clear.

```
<?php
  include 'db.php';
  $db=new db;

  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
    if($_POST['act']=='save'){
      $content=$_POST['content'];
      $id=25;

      $query="UPDATE content SET content=? WHERE id=?";
      $db->execquery($query, 'si', array($content, $id));
      echo json_encode(array("response"=>'success'));
      exit();
    }
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
  <title>summernote</title>
  <!-- include jquery -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 

  <!-- include libraries BS3 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- include summernote -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/summernote.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/summernote.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('.summernote').summernote({
          toolbar: [
            // [groupName, [list of button]]
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
            ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
            ['color', ['color']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
            ['height', ['height']]
          ]
        });

      $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        content=$('.summernote').summernote('code');
        data='act=save&content='+content;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "JSON",
          data: data,
        })
        .fail(function(e){
            alert(e.response);
        })
        .done(function(data){
            if(data.response=='success'){
                alert('success!');
            }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input">Text</label>
    <textarea class="form-input" id="input"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="contents">Contents</label>
    <textarea name="text" class="summernote" id="contents" title="Contents"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyway when I just type simple texts in summernote the values are being saved but when I paste some text from msword something like that the values being saved are cut.

I tried something that when I press submit I am also putting the summernote values into an extra textarea then when I paste the values manually in DB everything is good. I also tried copying the codeview values then paste in DB manually then it's good also. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I fixed it with:

Javascript

`content = encodeURIComponent($('.summernote').summernote('code'));`

PHP

`urldecode($_POST[content])`

Comment: Warning

The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results. php.net